# Service Reference Auto Generated Duplicate Binding Configurations in App.Config in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

I have two different third parties wsdl files. When I add service references to my project. It creates endpoints automatically in app.config. These endpoints are

```
 <endpoint address="http://tgif1.bestovernite.com:10010/web/services/TQUOTEAPI.TQUOTEAPIHttpSoap11Endpoint/"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TQUOTEAPISoap11Binding"
        contract="OverniteLTL.TQUOTEAPIPortType" name="TQUOTEAPIHttpSoap11Endpoint" />

    <endpoint address="http://208.98.171.28:10021/web/services/TQUOTEAPI.TQUOTEAPIHttpSoap11Endpoint/"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TQUOTEAPISoap11Binding1"
        contract="DiamondLineService.TQUOTEAPIPortType" name="TQUOTEAPIHttpSoap11Endpoint1" />
```

Please note that bindingConfiguration attributes are same just a difference is that 1 is appending in second one. just to make it unique.
When I make a client of second endpoint in the code to create request then it throws the following exception.
 The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/basicHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'TQUOTEAPISoap11Binding'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration.

While googling I found a solution for this exception. add the binding tag in web.config in this way.

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TQUOTEAPISoap11Binding1"/>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

It does not work for me and I am getting the same exception.
I think, Diamondline service(second endpoint) client trying to find TQUOTEAPISoap11Binding in config file, but it has been created for first one. It is just my thought, I am not confirmed about it.
I will be thankful to you, if you help me in this regard.